# I don't make HashMap in HashMap {Java}

Tags: java, hashmap

I need to put a `HashMap` to another `HashMap`, but never get second `HashMap` values.

Example:

```
HashMap<UUID, HashMap<String, String>> hash = new....
```

But the `hash.get(#UUID)` call returns an `Object` instance, not a `String`. How to create `HashMap` with 3 keys like `HashMap<K, V, C>`?

Thanks.

Comment: If you use  `get` on the first hashmap, it will return you an object (of type hashmap). You need to 'get' on that object to get the string

Comment: Example?, I don't understand you, I need String and that always return Object(HashMap)

Comment: What are the other two keys to your three key `HashMap`? You have one key, `UUID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to call a second time `get`

```
hash.get(/*key*/) // This will get you the inner HashMap (thus the Object you're talking about)
    .get(/*key*/); // This will get you a String object from the inner HashMap
```

Comment: Mhm, I try that later, Thank you for answer, but also I need put in that and I can't, hash.get(UUID).put("K","V"); And it doesn't work

Comment: @M3P3S It should work. Be careful not to use the same keys twice.